# Handling a non existing file with htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following code written by me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^join_([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ /index.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^secure_access&u=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)&p=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ /index.php?a=do_login&username=$1&password=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^external_funding/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=add_funds&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^investment_stats/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=deposit&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^affiliate_stats/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=commissions&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_pz/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=11&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_pm/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=18&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_pa/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=43&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_btc/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=48&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_adv/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=56&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^earning_stats_bw/?$ /index.php?a=earnings&type=earning&ec=999&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

I actually redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, rewrite the URL whenever the file/directory doesn't exist and finally redirect to index.php in case of no valid conditions.

However, I'd like to redirect all 404 requests to a custom page named "error.php" but I'm unable to do it due to last rewrite rule.
My site is based on a single file named "index.php" that contains all pages and then prints them by reading the GET paramater "a" (just look at 3 first rewrite rules join, secure_access and earning_stats).
So there are many other pages such as:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?a=logout
```

That is read by my PHP script as:

```
http://domain.com/logout
```

Without the need to add it on .htaccess (preview: http://puu.sh/rnYhq/8003fa32cc.png)

It may sound hard or bad explained, just feel free to ask me for further info.

Comment: I don't see a 404 declaration in your file. What have you tried?

Comment: I have also tried: ErrorDocument 404 "page not found" but it's not working.

Comment: This is the problem. `http://example.com/earning_stats/` is not a real directory or file. So you should get a 404, but you have a rewriterule so it knows what to do in this situation. If you put a rule that redirects all 404's that's going to mess with all your rewrites as well. You need to handle 404s in your code at this point which is how wordpress does it since you have a catchall for the last rule. Otherwise, you need to change your setup.

Comment: You're definitely right, unfortunately the software I'm using is encoded with IonCube 9 so I basically have no access to source code of index.php, and I cannot execute plain PHP code because pages are handled by Smarty (a template engine). Any solution / workaround?

Comment: What actually happens when you use an invalid URL? What response does the app give? What headers?